# Django ForeignKey(User), autocomplete

Tags: mysql, django

When some user create an object in the admin panel, I want that the author field of that object to be the user's name (The user that created it). How can I do it ?

I have something like this :

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want to know what user created each object.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to do what James Bennett (one of the Django core contributors) describes how to do [here](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/24/admin/).